# Parameter not provided to the stored procedure when I use Dapper DynamicParameter from C# dictionary

Tags: c#, t-sql, stored-procedures, dapper, dynamicparameters

I'm using Dapper `DynamicParameters` in order to send a parameters dictionary from my .NET Core application to SQL Server, but I get an error:

> Parameter @cityName1 is not provided

But when I trace the query, I can see it is present.

This is the code :

Fill in the dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, object> cities = new Dictionary<string, object>();
cities.Add("@cityName1", "New-York");
cities.Add("@cityId1", 123);
```

The call to Dapper:

```
DynamicParameters dbArgs = new DynamicParameters();

foreach (var pair in cities)
{
   dbArgs.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
}

return await connection.QueryAsync<Provider>(SQL_GET_LINKS_BY_CITIES, dbArgs);
```

The stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[hp_GetLinksByCities]
    (@cityName1 NVARCHAR(25),
     @cityId1 INT)
AS
BEGIN
    -- code
END
```

The trace from the profiler:

```
exec sp_executesql N'[dbo].[hp_GetLinksByCities]',N'@cityName1 nvarchar(4000),@cityId1 int',@cityName1=N'Marseille',@cityId1=1970
```

The error

Original (in French):

> La procédure ou fonction 'hp_GetLinksByCities' attend le paramètre '@cityName1', qui n'a pas été fourni.

Translated to English:

> The stored procedure or function 'hp_GetLinksByCities' is expecting a '@cityName1' parameter which was not supplied

When I executed this code in SSMS, I got the same error, but with this syntax, it's working fine :

```
exec [dbo].[hp_sp_GetDirectoryPageLinksByCities] @cityName1=N'Marseille',@cityId1=1970
```

Usually, Dapper sends order that way and It's working very well. Why does it act differently this time ?

I have no clue of what's wrong... do I need to use the `DynamicParameter` differently?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: `exec sp_executesql N'[dbo].[hp_GetLinksByCities]', ...` isn't passing the parameters to the proc though, just to `sp_executesql`. (Note I don't know how to fix that, I know nothing about Dapper, just explaining why the error occurs.)

Comment: I'm a little confused - the proc takes 2 parameters only, but you seem to be adding lots in a loop - in the general way, that won't work; you'd need an execute per pair, and if you're doing an execute per pair, you don't need dynamic args at all. Random thing to try: take the `@` out of the string, i.e. `cities.Add("cityName1", "New-York");` etc

Comment: @MarcGravell Actually the real SP accepts 25 parameters x2. I simplified the code here but I forgot to remove the foreach line ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing `commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure` in the call to Dapper, so it is issuing it as a vanilla text query, which means it is issuing just `hp_GetLinksByCities` by itself as a raw command, *which doesn't pass down the args*.

Note: we've *discussed* interpreting single word commands as stored procedures automatically, but to date: we haven't made that change - so the command-type needs to be specified explicitly.